# Using animate parameters with shorthand jQuery effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to do a simple `slideDown()` in jQuery, such as:

```
$(".zip").delay(1000).slideDown();
```

But I wanted to use the `useTranslate3d` parameter (for the [jQuery.Animate-Enhanced plugin](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/)), can I simply apply the parameter to the `slideDown()` function, or do I need to also call the `animate()` function like so:

```
$(".zip").delay(1000).slideDown().animate({
    useTranslate3d: true,
});
```

Or could I simply do:

```
$(".zip").delay(1000).slideDown({
    useTranslate3d: true,
});
```

Comment: Have you tried before asking?

Comment: Obviously, but I'm not sure how to test to see if it's enabled, other then by seeing if the animations are smoother.